# How does NSMutableArray change object index you use removeObjectAtIndex?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

While using NSMutableArray, I can `addObject:` and then use `removeObjectAtIndex:0` to remove the object in the front. From the docs:

> To fill the gap, all elements beyond index are moved by subtracting 1 from their index.

So that means, object at index 2 becomes 1, 3 becomes 2, etc. Does that mean each object is moved to index-1 or is the "index" value updated to be index-1 and the 0 position is just empty.

I realize how stupid the latter sounds, but that one line gives me the impression that that is what's happening.

Comment: arrays can't have gaps. there won't be any empty slots after calling *-removeObjectAtIndex:*

Comment: if you think about it, the description given doesn't allow for any "holes" anyway. you can try it on paper to see.

Comment: if you're asking about how the storage actually works--you will have to check out the source code CoreFoundation... but you really don't have to worry about it.

Comment: What does your question have to do with the title? Your title and question are completely different.

Comment: There's a brilliant write-up at the following link which explores the innards of NSMutableArray; http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/03/05/exposing-nsmutablearray/

Comment: @maddy Sorry about that, I've fixed that now. I'm not sure what was going through my head at the time..

Comment: @Luke That's very detailed and I'm exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: @Luke "__NSArrayM never reduces its size" that's what I was wondering. So if you keep removing at index 0, and adding repeatedly, the array will keep increasing in memory even though the number of objects in it remain the same(!)

Answer (score 3):

As in most array implementations, it is likely that NSMutableArray has knowledge of the size of the objects it is storing and the total number of the objects it is storing. With this knowledge it can then reasonably do pointer math to access the object of interest. But, if you are really interested in understanding how NSMutableArray works, I would recommend that you examine CFArray which is the CoreFoundation variant of NSMutableArray. You can examine the open source code here:

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.14/CFArray.c

Comment: Sorry, I think my title may have mislead you. I've updated it to match the description for the question. This seems different from what I was wondering.

Answer (score 1):

As to your actual question, no, there will never be gaps in the array. `NSArray`s cannot hold `nil` values. Compare and contrast with an `NSPointerArray`.

Re: your title, the actual allocation and deallocation of memory is an opaque implementation detail and arrays may use any kind of internal storage — C arrays, linked lists, anything. [This article](http://darkdust.net/writings/objective-c/nsarray-enumeration-performance) (supplying the link to which is why I think this worthy of an answer when others have already answered the question by comment) takes a look at the performance characteristics of `NSArray` and suggests a non-trivial approach is being used internally, as performance scales differently depending on the type of enumeration.

Comment: Good point, I've updated the title since it seemed off from the question.